# Why Doesn't iOS Autorotate a View loaded from a Nib after it was released by didReceiveMemoryWarning?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, autorotate, didreceivememorywarning

[My iPad app](http://designsceneapp.com/) makes heavy use of autorotation. This is great. However, I've noticed that if a hidden view is released by the default implementation of `didReceiveMemoryWarning` (as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1294633/iphone-dev-in-didreceivememorywarning-or-every-time)), when the view is re-loaded from the nib and I happen to be in landscape, it loads it in portrait. This wreaks havoc with the interface until I rotate the iPad manually and force it to go to the proper orientation.

I had assumed that iOS would load the view in the current orientation; that's what it does when the app launches. But it no, not after being unloaded by `didReceiveMemoryWarning`. Why not? And how can I get it to do that?

Comment: Is the view outside of the view hierarchy (not a subview of the UIViewController view)?

Comment: @dbarker - Nope, in fact it's the main view of the app.

Comment: @dbarker Ah, but looking more carefully, I see that it's subviews of that view that are not properly rotated. Subviews included in the nib are properly rotated. Sort of. Hrm. Something might be up with my `-willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration:`
 method. Maybe it's not getting called because the rotation isn't animated?

Comment: Yes, neither `-willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:` nor `-willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration:` gets called. They're both called on app launch…

Comment: Sounds right - the rotation callbacks won't get called when the view (re) loads. For the views that aren't managed by a nib, you'll need to adjust them manually to the orientation that UIViewController#interfaceOrientation returns. Not sure, but possible that this is what the nib does behind the scenes.

Comment: Hrm. In what method should I do that? It's already done automatically on launch, so I'd need to be able to tell whether or not the view is loading on launch.

Comment: That check should happen in viewDidLoad. If I'm understanding right, viewDidLoad is always orienting these views one way and the will/didRotate messages are correcting it (on launch) if it's wrong. Since there are cases where viewDidLoad happens and will/didRotate are not sent, viewDidLoad has to set these views up correctly for the current orientation. The will/didRotate messages will still handle further orientation changes.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I figured; see answer below. Kind of annoying, though. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer, determined thanks to pointers from [dbarker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/78279/dbarker), is that the view controller's rotation methods, including `-willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:` and `-willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration:`, will not be called when a view is reloaded after a the default implementation of `didReceiveMemoryWarning` has unloaded the view. I've no idea why it would be different on app launch, but I do have a workaround

What I did was to set a boolean ivar, named `unloadedByMemoryWarning`, to `YES` in `didReceiveMemoryWarning`, like so:

```
- (void) didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    unloadedByMemoryWarning = YES;
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}
```

Then, in `viewDidLoad`, if that flag is true, I set it to `NO` and then call the rotation methods myself:

```
if (unloadedByMemoryWarning) {
    unloadedByMemoryWarning = NO;
    [self willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:self.interfaceOrientation duration:0];
    [self willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:self.interfaceOrientation duration:0];
    [self didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:self.interfaceOrientation];
}
```

Kinda sucks that I have to do this, but it does work, and now I'm less concerned about getting killed by iOS for using too much memory.

Comment: I am facing the same issue in my iPad app. This is kind of weird behavior but your solution helped me.

Comment: Tried that solution but it's not doing it on my end unfortunately. Bleh... *digs on*

Answer (score 1):

1. I think iOS 5 might fix this.
2. For iOS 4.3, I've had good luck with another fix. After the load from nib:

   ```
   [parent.view addSubview:nibView];  
   nibView.frame = parent.view.frame;  
   [nibView setNeedsLayout];
   ```

   If that worked, you could jettison the `unloadedByMemoryWarning` logic, since it's safe to do every load. Got the tip & code (basically) from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6955974/45813).